# Meaning of "share with each other" Vs."share with others"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Right off the bat I will state that I'm neither a linguist nor an etymologist, but I *am* a serious English language enthusiast.

On to my question: I have a need to convey that a specific group of people share something (e.g. their wisdom, knowledge, wealth, etc.) with other people that are *not necessarily* part of said group.

If I said, for example:

> Philosophers can share their wisdom with each other.

I would imply that sharing should only take place within members of the Philosophers group.

Since I need to convey that such sharing should also take place with members *outside* the Philosophers group my thinking is to change the above sentence to:

> Philosophers can share their wisdom with others.

I am concerned, however, that this may create the impression that wisdom can be shared *only* outside of the Philosophers group and not between their members, which is not my intention.

Is my concern valid?

Comment: *Is my concern valid?* Only in the far reaches of pedantry and the absence of context. I assume that you are not simply testing an isolated sentence, and it would help if you included context. That said, **"Others"** is capable of being construed as "anyone in the world", and philosophers will tell you that the set of philosophers is within that set. I understand that "others" can also have the meaning "other philosophers", but the inclusion of context will make this clear. The alternative is to omit **"with others"** as this is the phrase that is causing the trouble.

Comment: @Greybeard that's good enough for me. If you add your comments as reply I will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above:

> Is my concern valid?

Only in the far reaches of pedantry and the absence of context. I assume that you are not simply testing an isolated sentence, and it would help if you included context.

That said, "**Others**" is capable of being construed as "anyone in the world", and philosophers will tell you that the set of philosophers is within that set.

I understand that "**others**" can also have the meaning "other philosophers", but the inclusion of context will make this clear.

The alternative is to omit "**with others**" as this is the phrase that is causing the trouble.